# How to improve using Android camera with some image processing

Tags: android, performance, android-camera, augmented-reality

I'm building an AR app on android with some image processing, the way I handle the camera is that I create a fake surface:

```
        SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(context);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
```

Then Use `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer` to get the camera buffers and send the buffer to some shared buffer using `System.arraycopy( data, 0, Buffer.m_data, 0, data.length);` where as the `Buffer.m_data` is shared with my main activity.

In my main activity I would run a loop, get the shared buffer, send it to my NDK code, get it back and then display it as an image:

```
if( m_bitmap == null ){
    m_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( m_width, m_height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
}
m_bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer( ByteBuffer.wrap(m_imData.m_data) );

img.setImageBitmap( m_bitmap );
```

Where as `img` is an `ImageView` that shows the processed buffer.

All this works REALLY slow. I believe that part of the problem is how I work with the camera.

Could you notice the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Refreshing the bitmap on an `ImageView` *is* an extremely slow process, so i'm not sure the issue comes from the camera.

Comment: Thought so - How would you show an image without using an ImageView?

Comment: If you're aiming at performance and if the processing you're doing in the NDK part supports massive parallelization, you could use hardware-accelerated rendering. Instead of displaying using `setPreviewDisplay`, use `setPreviewTexture` and do your processing in an OpenGL shader.
An other option could be to use [Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html). I've never tried it, though...

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you would need a [Canvas and Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) to get this done much faster.